Street racing - mechanic recruited by FBI to bring down his boss
I watched a movie two years back, I forgot the name but remember the plot. It's about this guy getting hired to work for some rich bad guys car collection, he works with another mechanic who does not really like him. Somewhere down the line the FBI makes him start working with them to take the bad guy down. The new mechanic gets involve with the bosses daughter. and he has the police in his pocket. In one part of the movie he gets in a car chase with police then when they see its him they don't do anything. I another part he tries to put some type of device in his office because the FBI told me to and he almost gets caught and finds his way the the daughters room. It's kind of a street racing movie. 
I saw it on Netflix about two years ago. I think it's a low budget movie. Also in the movie his friend races with a blue Civic, I think he drives a black muscle car and the boss's daughter drives a Shelby Cobra.
Please help me I been looking for so long.

possible duplicate of Please help me find the name of this movie.  Please delete one or the other, you asked the exact same question twice.

Best to delete the other one, though, because this one has more details. BTW, John, how old is this movie (assuming you didn't see it in theaters)?

No I did not see it in the theatres. I seen it on netflix about two years about in the same category of a movie names Crash and burn, I think there low budget movies. Also in the movie his friend races with a blue civic, I think he drives a black muscle car and the bosses daughter drives a Shelby cobra.

@JohnGreen Thanks. I have a good match for you.

Ya that's it!! Thanks a lot and that was fast. @Walt

Finish Line from 2008 with Scott Baio as the villain seems like a match. From an online synopsis:

Mitch Camponella (Samuel Page) is a badass driver whose mistakes on the track cost his father $60,000. Wracked by guilt, Mitch accepts a lucrative job as a mechanic for flashy billionaire importer/exporter Frank Chase (Baio) and soon finds himself thrust into the middle of a covert FBI investigation. The target? Frank Chase himself, who turns out not to be that great a guy. Sumbitch sells weapons to terrorists!
Mitch ends up going undercover for the Feds, though things get complicated when he falls head over heels for Chase's hot daughter (Taylor Cole). Can he put his street smarts to work and put Chase behind bars?

Also, the film's IMCDb page lists both a blue Civic and a Shelby Cobra replica.

